# Sort a string date array, if date format:- "Feb-01-2018"?

Tags: javascript

I want to sort an array according to month. The dates are in string format:-

`datesArray = [
  "May-17-2018",
  "Jan-06-1",
  "Nov-29-2018",
  "Nov-01-2018",
  "Apr-12-2018",
  "Aug-09-2018",
  "Feb-18-2018",
  "Feb-08-2018",
  "Jan-28-2018",
  "Jan-26-2018",
  "Mar-15-2018",
  "Oct-04-2018",
  "Jan-25-2018",
  "Jun-14-2018",
  "Dec-27-2018",
  "Jan-29-2018",
  "Jan-21-2018",
  "Jan-16-2018",
  "Jan-20-2018",
  "Mar-22-2018",
  "Feb-01-2018",
  "Mar-01-2018",
  "Mar-08-2018",
  "Apr-26-2018",
  "Feb-22-2018",
  "Apr-19-2018",
  "Mar-29-2018",
  "Sep-06-2018",
  "Apr-05-2018",
  "May-03-2018",
  "May-10-2018",
  "Feb-15-2018",
  "Jul-12-2018"
]`

I have implementd this code, but according to this code sort my number.

```
 datesArray.sort(function(a,b) {
  a = a.split('-').reverse().join('');
  b = b.split('-').reverse().join('');
  return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
 });
```

Tell me how to done this. I have search so many, but can't find out any result.

Comment: what about this value? `"Jan-06-1"`

Comment: You can't sort dates as strings while they're containing the months names. If you want to be able to sort them as strings you should first format the dates
 as: `yyyy-mm-dd`. Another option is to create date-objects and then sort the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the given dates to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant dates and sort them by string.

```js
var array = ["May-17-2018", "Jan-06-2017", "Nov-29-2018", "Nov-01-2018", "Apr-12-2018", "Aug-09-2018", "Feb-18-2018", "Feb-08-2018", "Jan-28-2018", "Jan-26-2018", "Mar-15-2018", "Oct-04-2018", "Jan-25-2018", "Jun-14-2018", "Dec-27-2018", "Jan-29-2018", "Jan-21-2018", "Jan-16-2018", "Jan-20-2018", "Mar-22-2018", "Feb-01-2018", "Mar-01-2018", "Mar-08-2018", "Apr-26-2018", "Feb-22-2018", "Apr-19-2018", "Mar-29-2018", "Sep-06-2018", "Apr-05-2018", "May-03-2018", "May-10-2018", "Feb-15-2018", "Jul-12-2018"];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getISO(s) {
        var months = { Jan: '01', Feb: '02', Mar: '03', Apr: '04', May: '05', Jun: '06', Jul: '07', Aug: '08', Sep: '09', Oct: '10', Nov: '11', Dec: '12' };
        return s.replace(/^(...)-(..)-(....)$/, (_, m, d, y) => [y, months[m], d].join('-'));
    }

    return getISO(a).localeCompare(getISO(b));
});
  
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a maps of your months.

```js
var datesArray = [
  "May-17-2018",
  "Jan-06-1",
  "Nov-29-2018",
  "Nov-01-2018",
  "Apr-12-2018",
  "Aug-09-2018",
  "Feb-18-2018",
  "Feb-08-2018",
  "Jan-28-2018",
  "Jan-26-2018",
  "Mar-15-2018",
  "Oct-04-2018",
  "Jan-25-2018",
  "Jun-14-2018",
  "Dec-27-2018",
  "Jan-29-2018",
  "Jan-21-2018",
  "Jan-16-2018",
  "Jan-20-2018",
  "Mar-22-2018",
  "Feb-01-2018",
  "Mar-01-2018",
  "Mar-08-2018",
  "Apr-26-2018",
  "Feb-22-2018",
  "Apr-19-2018",
  "Mar-29-2018",
  "Sep-06-2018",
  "Apr-05-2018",
  "May-03-2018",
  "May-10-2018",
  "Feb-15-2018",
  "Jul-12-2018"
];

var mapDates = {
  "Jan": 1,
  "Feb": 2,
  "Mar": 3,
  "Apr": 4,
  "May": 5,
  "Jun": 6,
  "Jul": 7,
  "Aug": 8,
  "Sep": 9,
  "Oct": 10,
  "Nov": 11,
  "Dec": 12
};

datesArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(mapDates[a.split('-')[0]] < mapDates[b.split('-')[0]]) return -1;
    if(mapDates[a.split('-')[0]] > mapDates[b.split('-')[0]]) return 1;
    return 0;
});

console.log(datesArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better convert the date string to date object before comparing.

```js
var datesArray = ["May-17-2018", "Jan-06-2017", "Nov-29-2018", "Nov-01-2018", "Apr-12-2018", "Aug-09-2018", "Feb-18-2018", "Feb-08-2018", "Jan-28-2018", "Jan-26-2018", "Mar-15-2018", "Oct-04-2018", "Jan-25-2018", "Jun-14-2018", "Dec-27-2018", "Jan-29-2018", "Jan-21-2018", "Jan-16-2018", "Jan-20-2018", "Mar-22-2018", "Feb-01-2018", "Mar-01-2018", "Mar-08-2018", "Apr-26-2018", "Feb-22-2018", "Apr-19-2018", "Mar-29-2018", "Sep-06-2018", "Apr-05-2018", "May-03-2018", "May-10-2018", "Feb-15-2018", "Jul-12-2018"];

 datesArray.sort(function(a,b) {
  var date_items = a.split('-');
  var date_a = Date.parse( date_items[0] + ' ' + date_items[1] + ' ' + date_items[2])
  date_items = b.split('-');
  var date_b = Date.parse( date_items[0] + ' ' + date_items[1] + ' ' + date_items[2])
  
  //date_a = Date.parse(a); //You can replace above parser with other appropriate one
  //date_b = Date.parse(b);
  return date_a - date_b;
 });
 
 console.log(datesArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in Chrome. By the looks of it Chrome's `Date` implementation accepts more/other parameter syntaxes for the constructor than other browsers:

```js
datesArray = [
  "May-17-2018",
  "Jan-06-1",
  "Nov-29-2018",
  "Nov-01-2018",
  "Apr-12-2018",
  "Aug-09-2018",
  "Feb-18-2018",
  "Feb-08-2018",
  "Jan-28-2018",
  "Jan-26-2018",
  "Mar-15-2018",
  "Oct-04-2018",
  "Jan-25-2018",
  "Jun-14-2018",
  "Dec-27-2018",
  "Jan-29-2018",
  "Jan-21-2018",
  "Jan-16-2018",
].map(date => new Date(date).toJSON().substr(0, 10)).sort((a,b) => { return a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0) })
```